# Why didn't Henry tell his wife what had happened to him?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-time-travelers-wife

In *The Time Traveler's Wife*, I know this may cause a time paradox, but when Henry is shot at the end why doesn't he tell his wife where or how he got shot so she can warn him when he visits her when she is older but he is still younger (not shot yet)? She could warn him to scare the animal away as soon as you appear (time traveled) to the snow and see it (e.g. make loud human noises). The hunter would know a human was there and not shoot.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't change the past like that, as said by Henry himself:

> **Clare:** But you get to see people from the past. People who are gone, like your mom.
>
> **Henry:** Yeah, but the thing is, you can't change what happens to them. I've tried. It just happens anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that line but remember it now. But wouldn't buying the lottery ticket be a paradox?  He would not have known the correct numbers had he not gone to the future, and is thus changing the past by buying the winning ticket. My thought was if he can do that, he can perhaps do other things.

Answer (score 2):

The book goes into this with a bit more detail; he discusses a time when he experienced an event twice, and the second time he experienced it, he (now the older version) tried to act differently than what he had, as the younger version, seen the older version do. He finds that he is unable to do so, as if some force is controlling him.

In a comment, you ask about him buying a lottery ticket. The Time Traveler's Wife seems to subscribe to the [Stable Time Loop](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StableTimeLoop) version of time travel. Characters cannot make things happen differently than how the time loop is. There can be events that happen only because of the characters, and the ultimate cause for the an event can be event itself (bootstrap paradox), but if something isn't in the loop, then it can't be added.

Comment: Uff I should read it not keep on rack